# how to use java to call Oracle stored routine with an IN parameter type as MyTable%ROWTYPE?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, user-defined-types, callable-statement, rowtype

I have a stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SID1.pkg_types AS 
    myTableRec  MYTABLE%ROWTYPE; 
END pkg_types;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp1(
    p_1 IN SID1.MyTableRec%TYPE
)as
begin  -- ...  
end;/
```

I need to make a jdbc call to sp1.

Environment:

```
 Oracle 19c and ojdbc11:21.8.0.0
```

So firstly I tried code like this:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call sp1(?) }");
OracleConnection conn = ... 
Struct struct = conn.createStruct("SID1.PKG_TYPES.MYTABLEREC", new Object[] {"v1", "v2"}); stmt.setObject(1, rec); 
stmt.execute();
```

got error when creating the struct:

**java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type "SID1.PKG_TYPES.MYTABLEREC"**

Secondly, I tried using SQLData interface and Type Map:

```
public class MyTable implements SQLData {
    readSQL() ...
    writeSQL() ...
}
typeMap.put("SID1.PKG_TYPES.MYTABLEREC", MyTable.class)
conn.setTypeMap(typeMap);

MyTable rec = new MayTable("v1", "v2", ...);
stmt.setObject(1, rec);
stmt.execute();
```

Now got error: **PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to "sp1"**

I googled around, and found a **work around** to

1. create a schema level type UDT which has all the columns as MYTABLE
2. create another sp2 using parameter "p_1 IN UDT", and invoke sp1 from sp2.

This work around is very tedious as MYTABLE has many columns, and I have to re-assign all p_1 attributes before sp2 invokes sp1 (seems PL/SQL have not way to do an 'object' level copy to make it easier).

Any body has a simpler solution? Or point out what's wrong with my 2 failed approaches? I have to point out that my above approaches works on a normal plain user defined type.  The real issue is the ROWTYPE in the type definition. Thank you for your time to read all those!